# How can I remove two edges of a shape but leave the fill in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, stroke, fill

I have a hexagon with a border. I can remove one edge from it, and keep the fill colour in it. But if I want to remove a second edge, the fill disappears, because the node has been deleted - as you can see.

[image]

Is there a way to keep the fill and only use one shape?

I can do it with two:

[image]

But that means doubling the complexity of the model - and a lot of work to change it all. Is there a way to achieve the effect above with one shape?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No you cannot achieve the similar effect with a single shape because stroke and fill is one single property. The first case when you remove one edge of the stroke, the hexagon shape is not disturbed because still there is a top node. Once you remove the other edge, the complete node is removed as it is not connected to any other node, the fill gets adjusted to the new nodes. The only way you can do is with two objects as you have done (the other being converting a single shape to two shapes by using stroke to path, which is one shape and using break apart command so that fill is another shape)

Comment: Can I make a "floating" node?

Comment: Nope. It is not possible. Without connecting to other node with a stroke, you cannot add a single floating node.

Comment: Join selected endnodes with a new segment : If more than two end nodes are selected, pairs of end nodes will be joined with a segment, starting with the end nodes closest to each other until either zero or one end nodes are selected. If zero or one end node is selected at the start, then any adjacent stretches of selected nodes (including non-end nodes), will have their middle nodes removed, leaving one segment between outermost selected nodes.- http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Paths-Editing.html#Paths-Editing-Node.

Comment: Note that this is down to the SVG standard which simply does not allow for such objects (which makes sense). If Inkscape introduced such objects, the loss of compatibility to ordinary SVGs wouldn’t make up for it.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Ahh okay, that's nice to know - it's doing the right thing.